# Sitecore Forms, EXM doesn't show up after upgrading to 9.3

Tags: sitecore-forms, exm, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade Db from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9.3.

I have followed the below steps:

1. Extracted the database upgrade scripts from the Database Upgrade Script.zip file that you downloaded earlier.
2. Executed the CMS_core_master_web8x.sql script for the Core, Master, and Web databases.
3. Executed the CMS_core.sql script for the Core database only.
4. Installed fresh sitecore 9.3 site
5. Used the upgraded databases(core, master,web) to fresh Sitecore 9.3
6. After changed the upgrade databases the below apps are missing in sitecore 9.3 Launchpad (Forms, Exm, marketing automations).

Anyone help on this issue ?

Comment: The buttons from Sitecore Launchpad are read from Core database: /sitecore/client/Applications/Launchpad/PageSettings/Buttons. I guess your Core database was not upgraded correctly and these items are missing. You may try to install the missing items from a clean Sitecore 9.3 core (via Sitecore package) database and see if these applications work then. If you have all Sitecore custom items serialized (unicorn/tds) you may consider installing them on a Vanilla Sitecore 9.3 skipping the database upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

The steps you added here are not complete steps for the upgrade. You need to perform all the steps in the upgrade guide for database upgrades. you can download the upgrade guide
from here - https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/93/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_93_Initial_Release.aspx

I am adding all the steps in sort here -

-Download below file from the above link -

- Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (update package for 8.2).zip
- Sitecore Update Installation Wizard 4.0.1 rev.00153 for 8.x-9.0.zip
- Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (upgrade files).zip

-Copy these files in a temp location – eg d:/temp-

- Unzip - Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (update package for 8.2).zip on the same location-
  This will have a .update package for the upgrade - Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (update package for 8.2).update
- Unzip - Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (upgrade files).zip on the same location -
  This file will have multiple zip files -
  [image]

-Disable the Sitecore modules

-Executed the script-

- CMS_core_master_web8x.sql script for the Core, Master, and Web databases.
- CMS_core.sql script for the Core database only.

-Deploy the new databases – sort cut way to use the databases from the vanilla 9.3 instance

- Copy the connection string excluding core, master and web database connection string from the vanilla 9.3 and paste it into the current 8.2 Sitecore ( which you will upgrade)
- Copy the core connection string and paste it above the core DB connection string and change the name to security

-Disable xDB

-Install the Sitecore Update Installation Wizard 4.0.1 rev. 00153 for 8.x-9.0.zip package using Install a package feature

-Install the Sitecore 9.3.0 rev. 003498 (update package for 8.2).update using update installation wizard (for more see chapter 6 in upgrade guide)

- Analyze the package
- Install the package

-Perform post-upgrade steps from the guide

From your steps it looks like you have not yet done the .update package installation, the SQL script will only create few new tables but the actual data is part of .update package.

I hope this will help you.